# Is it safe to add additional values to a TXT record in DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record

In Dynamics 365 we need to be able to authenticate our domain for sending marketing emails. We have followed the advice in the Microsoft article below and now need to add the DNS records.

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/marketing/mkt-settings-authenticate-domains#:~:text=all%20new%20instances.-,Authenticate%20a%20domain,of%20existing%20authenticated%20domains%20opens.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/marketing/mkt-settings-authenticate-domains#:%7E:text=all%20new%20instances.-,Authenticate%20a%20domain,of%20existing%20authenticated%20domains%20opens.)

The TXT record it gives in the configuration is for the top level domain of our organisation. That is the one we want to authenticate. The thing is that our DNS already has a TXT record with the '@' symbol. I understand that this is a shortcut to the top level domain. If I were to add the additional value to that existing record of the key given in Dynamics 365, will that cause any issues? Is it safe to do that?

The text record already has values for SPF and some other keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to have multiple values in a single TXT record.

Route53 (AWS DNS service) for example will not allow multiple TXT records for a specific value in a zone. Other DNS providers will allow you to break them out, but if you dig for TXT records you'll get all of them back anyway so there really isn't a reason to break them up.

Comment: Thanks, I actually called up Azure support to double check and they said that it works like that in Azure.

Comment: Ah good to know! I don't have as much experience with Azure DNS.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the semi-common things that store values in TXT records at the root are smart enough to have some kind of identifier in the record, or just accept all the TXT records and just look through them for the value they want.

Common TXT types that with some identifiers. SPF TXT record will start with `v=spf1`. DMARC with `v=DMARC1;` Google site verifications will start with `google-site-verification=`.

From your [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/dynamics365/marketing/mkt-settings-authenticate-domains#authenticate-a-domain)

```
TXT value: d365mktkey=abc123abc123abc123abc123
```

The `d365mktkey=` part is used to define this record is for dynamics.

Anyway, nothing should break by adding another TXT record.

Comment: Thanks, it won't be a new text record, it will be adding to the existing one labelled with '@'. Can you confirm that is right as the hostname it gives in dynamics 365 is the same as the top level domain for the organisation?

Comment: @RLBChrisBriant You should have a separate TXT record for each type. So one for `v=spf1`, another for `v=d365mktkey`, and so on.

Comment: But the one it is giving in Dynamics is the same as the top level domain. We already have one for '@'.

Comment: I think the description below for TXT records means that in Azure DNS I can add a new line to the existing "@" one. Is that correct? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#:~:text=A%20TXT%20record%20set%20can,(across%20all%20records%20combined).

Comment: You should be should be adding a new TXT record. Multistring text records are for something different. You can have multiple TXT records under `@`. Adding it as another string in an existing record will probably break something.

Comment: I found out that in Azure the text records hold multiple values. You cannot add a new text record with the same name. This was shown to me by a Microsoft support representative when I logged a ticket with them. I think it is just designed that was in Azure and is just a quirk of the interface. Other providers probably require you to enter the text records for the same host name as separate records.